# How to represent identical objects with unique names in Kotlin data class from JSON

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using the NHL API to get live game data.  Part of the API response for a live game comes back with an object called `players` which contains more objects whose names are the players' IDs.  The data looks like this:

```
...
},
"players" : {
    "ID8470966" : { ... },
    "ID8474628" : { ... },
    etc.
},
...
```

My question is, how can I represent this in a data class?  Normally I would use something like `List<Player>`, but the data isn't represented in the JSON as a list, and each time the API is called for a different game, the names of the player objects are going to be different based on their IDs.

Is there a way to represent those player objects using a dynamic id that comes back from the API?

Comment: Looks like a Map.

Comment: Instead of defining `"players"` as `List<Player>`, can you try with `List<Map<String, Any>>`

Comment: @Tenfour04 can you elaborate on what the data class would look like using a map?

Comment: `players` would be of type `Map<String, Any>`, or essentially `Map<String, CustomType>` if you can define `CustomType` class by looking at the API response with the fields that are part of what you've shown as `{ ... }`